# Google Cloud Natural Language API - Event Detection

Tags: events, nlp

Does Google Cloud Natural Language API provide event detection of events such as disinvestment?

Ex : If there is a news article on a government disinvesting in an entity (say exit power generation sector), does Google's NLP API catch this as an event?

Thanks,
Bhasker

Answer (score 0):

I evaluated Google's NLP API and it did not. However, it's been a few months back when I evaluated it. Also, it didn't yet recognize dates as entities. Hope that helps. I'm sure they'll be improving it soon, especially with their recent purchase of API.ai.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. That is helpful.